# Python segfault calculating exponential of negative (ppc64le)

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, qemu, powerpc

When calculating the exponential of a negative number in python 3.6 with Ubuntu 18.04 (ppcle64), I receive a segfault.

```
python -c "import math; math.exp(-1)"
qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
Segmentation fault
```

I am running this in Docker on macOS. Here are the steps to reproduce the error.

```
docker run --rm -it --platform linux/ppc64le ubuntu:18.04
apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq python3
python3 -c "import math; print(math.exp(0))"  # 1.0
python3 -c "import math; print(math.exp(-0))"  # 1.0
python3 -c "import math; print(math.exp(1))"  # 2.718281828459045
python3 -c "import math; print(math.exp(-1))"
```

This error does not happen when using the `debian:10` or `alpine` images.

Here is the output of `docker version` on my machine:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        afacb8b
 Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:21:11 2020
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.8
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       afacb8b
  Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:29:16 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

In case this is a bug, I submitted a report to Ubuntu at https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1871451 and to Docker's fork of qemu at https://github.com/moby/qemu/issues/10.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1871451/comments/1 : it looks to me from testing on a real ppc64le system that it's a bug in qemu user-mode emulation.

Comment: @dja thank you for testing on a true ppc64le machine

Comment: The other interesting thing to test would be upstream QEMU head-of-git, to see if it's a fix that's already been made upstream that just hasn't made it into the docker forked version.